# JavaBeans with Jasper's JasperReports and iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, javabeans

(Warning: I'm a Jasper n00b)

There seems to be a severe lack of useful info on using javabeans with ireports/jasperreports. I am just getting started with 4.0 and looking for a very simple Hello World JavaBean implementation. I tried using the PersonBean example they have included in the package, but no luck after following the directions outlined here: http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=83199#83213

I set it up as explained, but when I run the report and it comes back as "The report is empty". Does anyone have experience with this?

Secondly: 
I've found 2 books on amazon (with not so stunning reviews) on iReports and JasperReports.

1. The Definitive Guide to JasperReports
2. The Definitive Guide to iReport

Just wondering if anyone has used these? Based on the reviews and the fact that they were both published in 2007, I'm worried they won't be that helpful. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can find a couple of examples for creating Jasper reports using Java beans as datasource, here : [Create Jasper Reports With Java Bean Datasource](http://java-bytes.blogspot.com/2009/06/jasper-reports-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use the ultimate guides. They're not up to date with the latest edition of JasperReports or iReport, but they will get you up and going with all the functionality. You will have to be a bit of a detective when the iReport guide describes a menu that has changed, but for the most part they are good books that helped a me a lot.